# Push Single Table Data to Azure

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am Using a mobile app created using Xamarin-Forms, we have Azure as our Middle ware, so From SQLite Db of Mobile we push data to Azure, the app supports offline function as well. What i read on 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync/

We cannot Push a single table data to Azure, When in my application i call

```
await AzureServiceProvider.Instance.PushDataAsync();
```

does it always push all the tables data to azure?
If yes is there a way to push only table data related to the Page where CRUD operations has been performed?

Answer (score 3):

> does it always push all the tables data to azure?

Yes, it is. From help:

> This sync context helps preserve table relationships by tracking and
>   pushing changes in all tables a client app has modified when PushAsync
>   is called.

About next your question:

> is there a way to push only table data related to the Page where CRUD
>   operations has been performed

I am not using a standard sync. I tried for a long time but it's a lot of pain.
I created own ApiController in Azure Mobile App.

Comment: To expand on this answer (since it's so good), PushAsync pushes the operation queue, which includes a bunch of potentially interlinked changes. You can always create two table references - one offline for the sync pattern and then one online for when immediate changes need to happen.  There is also always the custom API capability.

Comment: @AdrianHall Do you have any example of Custom API?

Comment: There are plenty of samples for Custom APIs in the samples repositories of the backend services.

Comment: why do you think that it is a lot of pain? can you please give some examples?